# PHP MySQL Match() Against() Fulltext search not working for some keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I am working as php developer, and I have an issue with MySQL fulltext searches.

This is my query

```
select distinct j.jobid,headline,company,country,state,city,location,
date_format(str_to_date(posted_dt, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s' ), '%M %d, %Y') posted_dt,joblinks 
from jobs j 
left join job_filters jf on jf.jobid = j.jobid 
left join job_emptype_map em on j.jobid = em.jobid 
left join job_sub_emptype_map sem on em.jobid = sem.jobid and em.emp_type = sem.emp_type 
where status=1 
And MATCH (headline,description,pri_skills,company) AGAINST ('java developer' IN natural language MODE) > 1 
And MATCH (location,country,state,city,zipcode,other_loc) AGAINST ('california, United States' WITH QUERY EXPANSION ) > 1 
order by str_to_date(posted_dt,'%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') DESC limit 0,25
```

I am getting proper results with above query. But it is taking (Showing rows 0 - 24 (25 total, Query took 50.6951 seconds.)

when I change the keyword "ui developer" instead of "java developer" then I am getting 0 results

if i check keyword "ui developer" with like function then i am getting results.

I am not understanding why match function is working for some keywords only and why it is taking too much of time when my hosting plan is cloud.

Comment: FULLTEXT by default doesn't index certain words, including everying of 3 characters and shorter, and a list of stop words. This is configurable in MySQL, although you often can't when you're on a shared hosting plan. See [*stopwords*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and [*tuning*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Comment: The reason the original query is slow, is because of the terrible `order by` clause. Store the date as an actual date and add an index.

Answer (score 0):

I am on cloud server plan now and I have updated my query with like function, now my query is...

```
select distinct j.jobid,headline,company,country,state,city,location,date_format(str_to_date(posted_dt, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s' ), '%M %d, %Y') posted_dt,joblinks, (select count(distinct j.jobid) as jobcount from jobs j left join job_filters jf on jf.jobid = j.jobid left join job_emptype_map em on j.jobid = em.jobid left join job_sub_emptype_map sem on em.jobid = sem.jobid and em.emp_type = sem.emp_type where status = 1 and (concat(headline,' ',description,' ',pri_skills,' ',company) like '%java programer%' ) And ( country like '%United States%' ) ) jobcount from jobs j left join job_filters jf on jf.jobid = j.jobid left join job_emptype_map em on j.jobid = em.jobid left join job_sub_emptype_map sem on em.jobid = sem.jobid and em.emp_type = sem.emp_type where status=1 and (concat(headline,' ',description,' ',pri_skills,' ',company) like '%java programer%' )And ( country like '%United States%' ) order by str_to_date(posted_dt,'%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') DESC limit 0,25
```

i have writen select query between above query for pagination, above query is getting good results but taking too much of time, 
Pleas Note: my jobs table has around 50,000+ records

Comment: `order by str_to_date(posted_dt,'%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s')`  is what is killing you. You will force the database to execute this conversion 50.000 times, and after that it can sort it and get a subset of 25 rows from it. To do this right, store the date as an actual data and put an index on that column. Then sorting will be much faster, and getting a subset from it will be a piece of cake for your database.

Comment: And the where clause with the `%XYZ%` in the conditions is also very bad, as is searching in a concat of fields. You've basically done almost everything to make your query as slow as possible. FULLTEXT uses an actual index. Using like to search for texts with a starting and ending wildcard is terrible.

Comment: Next time keep your questions separate. The performance issue is a different problem, and it can't be solved in the comments to this answer alone.

Comment: thanks lot for your valuable information, I have made changes on date column as per your guidelines. but I am unable to understand what i have to do at where clause with the %XYZ% in the conditions ? please guide me. thank you

Comment: I have updated multiple columns values in to a single column (my new column name is 'search_job' ) with comma(, ) separated and i am retrieving the data from same column (search_job), so right now i am retrieving the data using like function from single column now my query is like '%search_job%',  but now also the performance is slow please check here https://www.reqsbook.com/all-keywords-search/united-states/java-developer-jobs/, please help me i am in trouble. thanks a lot

Comment: Like I said before, ask a new question (open a new topic using "ask question" at the top of the page). You won't get answers here, because it's a comment section below your own answer, and nobody except me sees you ask this.