# my website is working slow because of server or big data in mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, server

My website name is [reqsbook.com](https://www.reqsbook.com)
It is basically a job portal website, actually My website has around 1 lack jobs.

when I am searching jobs from my website it is performing too slow, actually I am using hostgator cloud server and I have hosted single domain here

I mad my website with very compress that as much as possible

I came to know through internet that i have to go for dedicated server or go for local server means I need to keep server in my location and maintain the website from there

I am thinking that if a took dedicated server then also the same problem may repeated because My website db are increasing day by day

If i go for local server....I don't have any knowledge on this

Please some one help me give me better idea

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have already explain about my query here please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788089/php-mysql-match-against-fulltext-search-not-working-for-some-keywords

Comment: you had not linked to that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's really slow. Only OOP and RDBMS can help you.

1. Customized your code so that same code need not execute many times.
2. Follow relation database management system. You can use indexing for fast searching. View table, temporary table, transaction  can help you to manage data easily.